# How to restrict any user to not upload duplicate data for same date on share point?

Tags: sharepoint

there is a SharePoint which is being used by multiple associate, in this sharepoint we have one required 'Date' field.

my question via an example:

In my SharePoint there are following field

```
Name Work1 Work2 Work3 Date
Rahul xxx  yyyy  zzz  04/17/23
Ram aaa  bbb  ccc  04/18/23 
Ram ddd  eee  fff  04/17/23
Ramesh ggg  hhh  iii  04/18/23
Ramesh ggg  hhh  iii  04/18/23
Rahul xxx  yyyy  zzz  04/18/23
```

(Rahul, Ram & Ramesh are the users)

I want is Rahul to not be able to enter/upload data for 04/18/23 & 04/17/23 again, since for both data he has already updated. there shouldn't be any duplication of data by a single user w.r.t Date, needless to mention he can edit existing data there is no problem.
(Kindly ignore xxx, yyyy, zzz and so on. These are just for example, these column can be anything.)

I did try many things but failed to solve above problem.